# AWS cognito - Is it possible to get google access token and refresh using aws access token when sign in using google in from aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When I signed in using google from aws cognito login page, it return back aws access token. Is it possible to retrieve google access token and refresh token using aws token. 
The url used to login -
https://example.auth.ap-southeast-1.amazoncognito.com//login?redirect_uri=redirect_uri&response_type=token&client_id=client_id.

How aws cognito handles refresh token when signed using google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no.

When you use the above URL to sign in using Cognito Userpool's OAuth endpoints, the response from google (i.e. tokens) is sent to the OAuth response endpoint for your userpool's domain ( https://example.auth.ap-southeast-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse ). Cognito checks the response from Google and generates id, access & refresh tokens and returns these to you depending on the scope and auth flows used. The response from Google i.e the google tokens is not stored somewhere and there are no Cognito API calls to retrieve the same.

As for token refresh when signed in using Google, that depends on your refresh token (returned by Cognito, and not Google's refresh token). As long as the refresh token returned from Cognito is valid, you can use it to get new id/access tokens. Again, this process does not involve Google at all.

Answer (score 2):

Not a fully working solution, but you can create custom attributes in cognito, and map them in the attribute mapping screen : 
[image]

Then when the user logged in, I saw that `access_token` and `expired_in` are captured. But I do not see `refresh_token`. Without `refresh_token` we wont be able to access the api from the backend. This seems so close alas !

Comment: Did you find any solution to get the refresh token. Please help if possible.

Comment: I tried to do it for Google Sign in but not getting access_token in my custom attribute.. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna build off of Sourav Sarkar's answer with an idea that you can try. If you **setup Google as an OIDC provider (not the one built in Cognito)** you may be able to try adding either one of these scopes:

1. offline
2. offline_access

The reason why we have to include these is because b**y default, Google only returns the Access Token** and not the Refresh Token. You have to specify that you would need the refresh token to retrieve it.

Fair warning though, I am not sure which one will work nor if adding any scope will work either since I have not tried it myself.

If you really need the refresh token for some reason e.g. Google API calls, **you can use Auth0 as this is built into their product.** I have not tried that either and this is also a problem I am facing right now since I don't want to use Auth0.

Here are my references:
[AWS OpenID Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html) [Oath 2.0 Scopes](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#Scopes) [Google OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#identify-access-scopes)

Comment: The scopes you suggest are not valid. Here's a response from Google: "Fehler 400: invalid_scope
Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid=[...], invalid=[offline, offline_access]}"