# How to get Google Refresh Token from AWS Cognito?

Tags: oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, google-oauth

I already read some topics here

1. [AWS cognito - Is it possible to get google access token and refresh using aws access token when sign in using google in from aws cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989259/aws-cognito-is-it-possible-to-get-google-access-token-and-refresh-using-aws-ac)
2. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3619.

The first one said I can't get Google Refresh Token from AWS Cognito.

The second one said AWS Cognito auto refresh Google Access Token and return to me when I call refresh AWS Cognito token.

**So what is true?**

I try to mapping Google Access Token and Refresh Token by using this

```
https://medium.com/graymatrix/using-custom-attributes-in-amazon-cognito-user-pool-288cd3128bae
```

After that i only get Google Access Token without Google Refresh Token.

> Can someone tell me how to get Google Refresh Token from AWS Cognito? Or the official AWS document on this issue.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this? If yes then can you please help me with the approach.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same problem: I use Google as federated ID provider and I only got an access token back. Tried different auth flows, read pages over pages of documentation. I finally found (by trial and error): Disable the **implicit grant** in the user pool. Then Cognito starts sending the refresh token. You then have to use the authorization code grant flow, of course. But that's rather simple using a library such as [oauth2-pkce](https://github.com/Tim-Erwin/oauth2-pkce).

Comment: So you mean that it's sending the google refresh token in the custom user attributes mapped to it? I'm still only getting the access token there..

Comment: This has nothing to do with mapped attributes. The payload simply includes the refresh token next to the access token if you disable implicit grant.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about the Google refresh token and not Cognito's user pool refresh token? For clarification, I'd need the Google refresh token to access google API on behalf of the user while they are offline (a cron job checking their Google calendar).

Comment: Cognito is for accessing services in AWS. I have no idea how to use it for Google services or if it's even possible any why you would wanna do that. I'm really surprised, you can get the Google access token from Cognito.